# Send notification to users

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a functionality that once a button is pressed it sends a chrome notification to all users logged in on the site, except for the one that pressed the button, that are stored in a user table in a database. For now, to keep things simple, I've made do with an alert that confirms the button is clicked, so the notification isn't written yet. The code I have is as follows.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="button">
        <form method="post">
            <input name="send" type="hidden" value="id"> <input name="send"
            type="submit" value="knop">
        </form>
    </div>

//if the 'send' button is clicked, it echoes a script saying the button is clicked. 
if (isset($_POST['send'])) 
    { 
      echo "<script>alert(\"the button is clicked\")</script>"; 
//  if the username is logged in AND the message is sent it should send the code script alert to all existing users in the 'user' table in the database.   

        if (isset($_SESSION['username']) AND ('$_POST[id]', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[message]') 
    { 
echo "<script>alert(\"yes\")</script>";
}
 }
    </body>
    </html>
```

The last if statement is wrong, I know. That's because I don't know what the logic is so that I can set the condition to be that the user is logged in and the message is sent by someone other than the logged in user. (so the posting of the comment effectively sends a notification to all other users logged in on the site).

I hope i'm clear enough for you to be able to help me.

Comment: Well if it's alive notification, you are going to need to use websockets..

Comment: Thanks, that I didn't know. Could you elaborate on that a little please?

Comment: You said "all users registered and stored in a user table"  and "to all other users logged in on the site" — Which one did you mean?

Comment: Sorry, misread your comment. I meant only logged in users. I edited my question that would do away with the confusion

Answer (score 0):

**This is working in `local` only.** Never test with `database`.

This is the example code for `Notification`. You just COPY and PASTE in your editor and save it as `.php` extension. The File must be placed in `www/`. and run it.The variable `var articles` to hold the data for push notification. And `setTimeout(function(){` this function to refer to as `timing` for two different notifications.

```
    <?php
$var;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Display browser Notification from Web Application Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var articles = [
["Send notification to users","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915185/send-notification-to-users"],
["Send notification to users","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915185/send-notification-to-users"],
["Send notification to users","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915185/send-notification-to-users"],
["Send notification to users","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915185/send-notification-to-users"],
["Send notification to users","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915185/send-notification-to-users"],
["Send notification to users","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915185/send-notification-to-users"],
["Send notification to users","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915185/send-notification-to-users"],
["Send notification to users","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915185/send-notification-to-users"],
["Send notification to users","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915185/send-notification-to-users"]
];


setTimeout(function(){ 
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var title=articles[x][0];
var desc='Most popular article.';
var url=articles[x][1];
notifyBrowser(title,desc,url);
}, 200000);



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () 
{

if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
{
Notification.requestPermission();
}

document.querySelector("#notificationButton").addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var title=articles[x][0];
var desc='Most popular article.';
var url=articles[x][1];
notifyBrowser(title,desc,url);
e.preventDefault();
});

//===================================
setInterval(function(e){ 
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var title=articles[x][0];
var desc='Most popular article.';
var url=articles[x][1];
notifyBrowser(title,desc,url);
e.preventDefault();

}, 5000);
//===================================
});

function notifyBrowser(title,desc,url) 
{
if (!Notification) {
console.log('Desktop notifications not available in your browser..'); 
return;
}
if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
{
Notification.requestPermission();
}
else {
var notification = new Notification(title, {
icon:'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-colored/700/09_bell-3-512.png',
body: desc,
});

// Remove the notification from Notification Center when clicked.
notification.onclick = function () {
window.open(url);      
};

// Callback function when the notification is closed.
notification.onclose = function () {
console.log('Notification closed');
};

}
}


</script>



<style type="text/css">
.hover{background-color: #cc0000}
 #container{ margin:0px auto; width: 800px} 
.button {
 font-weight: bold;
    padding: 7px 9px;
    background-color: #5fcf80;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-width: 1px 1px 3px !important;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #3ac162;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset;
}
.authorBlock{border-top:1px solid #cc0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Display browser Notification from Web Application Demo</h1>  

<h4>Click notification button</h4>
<a href="#"  id="notificationButton" class="button">Notification</a>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since the question is fundamentally about server push, providing a client side alternative to `alert` doesn't really help at all.

Comment: okay thank you may be he try to convert into server push. i just give an idea. bcz he dont know the logic @Quentin

Comment: The OP does know the logic. They were just using an alert instead of the notifications API. The problem is with triggering it for all users, not with the UI for the notification.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out though

Comment: if possible to change into server push and post that code its will help to us.